# Call functions that use specific types on Suds, Python

Tags: python, soap, types, suds

I have the following code:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

from suds.client import Client
url = 'https://webpay3gint.transbank.cl/WSWebpayTransaction/cxf/WSWebpayService?wsdl'

client = Client(url)

print client
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Service ( WSWebpayServiceImplService ) tns="http://service.wswebpay.webpay.transbank.com/"
   Prefixes (1)
      ns0 = "http://service.wswebpay.webpay.transbank.com/"
   Ports (1):
      (WSWebpayServiceImplPort)
         Methods (3):
            acknowledgeTransaction(xs:string tokenInput, )
            getTransactionResult(xs:string tokenInput, )
            initTransaction(wsInitTransactionInput wsInitTransactionInput, )
         Types (14):
            acknowledgeTransaction
            acknowledgeTransactionResponse
            cardDetail
            getTransactionResult
            getTransactionResultResponse
            initTransaction
            initTransactionResponse
            transactionResultOutput
            wpmDetailInput
            wsInitTransactionInput
            wsInitTransactionOutput
            wsTransactionDetail
            wsTransactionDetailOutput
            wsTransactionType
```

As you can see, some methods (initTransaction) use custom types (wsInitTransactionInput), how can I create an element of that custom type so I'm able to call initTransaction()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to write:

```
object = client.factory.create('wsInitTransactionInput')
client.service.initTransaction(object)
```

And it was in the suds documentation.